# NSFileManager OS X Last Modify Date

Tags: swift, macos, nsfilemanager

I have two questions on following code:

1) How to get the directory last modified/update date using the NSFileManager as coded below?

2) The array print out only the last record, how to get the result print out in

```
[
["ProjectName":"Project 1", "ProjectURL":"/Users/abc/Documents/MyProjectFolder/Project 1"],
["ProjectName":"Project 2", "ProjectURL":"/Users/abc/Documents/MyProjectFolder/Project 2"]
]
```

My code as below:

```
let documentsDirectoryURL =  try! NSFileManager().URLForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomain: .UserDomainMask, appropriateForURL: nil, create: true)

var bool: ObjCBool = false

myPath = NSURL(string: String(documentsDirectoryURL) + "MyProjectFolder")
var filevar: [String:String] = [:]
    if NSFileManager().fileExistsAtPath(myPath.path!, isDirectory: &bool) {
        if bool.boolValue {
            let fileManager =  NSFileManager.defaultManager()
            let files = try! fileManager.contentsOfDirectoryAtURL(myPath, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil, options: [])
            for file in files {
                let filename = file.lastPathComponent
                let fileurl = file.path
                if filename != ".DS_Store"{
                    filevar = ["ProjectName":filename!, "ProjectURL": fileurl!]
                }
             }
             print("Result:\n \(filevar)")
         }
     }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) get the modification date from the URL and compare the dates in the repeat loop.

2) create an array rather than a dictionary and append the dictionaries.

```
let fileManager = FileManager.default
let documentsDirectoryURL =  try! fileManager.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: true)

var isDir: ObjCBool = false

let myPath = documentsDirectoryURL.appendingPathComponent("MyProjectFolder")
var filevar = [[String:String]]()

var latestModificationDate = Date.distantPast
var latestFileURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/")
if fileManager.fileExists(atPath: myPath.path, isDirectory: &isDir) {
    if isDir.boolValue {
        do {
            let fileURLs = try fileManager.contentsOfDirectory(at: myPath, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil, options: .skipsHiddenFiles)
            for fileURL in fileURLs {
                let attributes = try! fileURL.resourceValues(forKeys:[.contentModificationDateKey, .nameKey])
                let filename = attributes.name!
                let modificationDate = attributes.contentModificationDate!
                if latestModificationDate.compare(modificationDate) == .orderedAscending {
                    latestModificationDate = modificationDate
                    latestFileURL = fileURL
                }
                filevar.append ( ["ProjectName":filename, "ProjectURL": fileURL.path])
            }
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
        print("Result:\n \(filevar)")
        print(latestFileURL, latestModificationDate)
    }
}
```

The option `.SkipsHiddenFiles` avoids the check for `.DS_Store`

Edit: Updated to Swift 4

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 4**

Here is some code to literally get the modified date for a specific URL. Note: It is important that your url has a scheme (such as file://).

```
func modifiedDate(atURL url: URL) -> Date? {
    if let attr = try? url.resourceValues(forKeys: [URLResourceKey.contentModificationDateKey]) {
        return attr.contentModificationDate
    }

    return nil
}
```